# C# binarywriter start and end of string

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, binaryreader, binarywriter

Im sending a large string `0.443+0.064+-0.120+-0.886+0.15167+-0.26754+0.95153` over a TCP socket-connection.

The message i recieve is not similar to the string i send. It is cut at random points, i.e. `43+0.064+-0.120+-0.886+0.15167+-0.26754+0`

How can i make sure the full string is read?

This is the clientcode:

```
public static void SendMessage(string message)
{
   if (socketConnection == null)
      {
        return;
      }
   using (BinaryWriter writer = new
   BinaryWriter(socketConnection.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII, true))
      {
         writer.Flush();
         writer.Write(message);
         writer.Flush();
       }
}
```

This is my servercode:

```
private void ListenForIncommingRequests()
{
     tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);
     tcpListener.Start();
     connectedTcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

     using (BinaryReader reader = new 
     BinaryReader(connectedTcpClient.GetStream()))
     {                   
         while (true)
          {
            string clientMessage = reader.ReadString();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Is "0.443+0.064+-0.120+-0.886+0.15167+-0.26754+0.95153" your entire string? Because if so, it's not very large. But if it is larger it could be a fragmentation issue. Try declaring your `string clientMessage` outside the `while (true)` scope and adding to the string like so: `clientMessage += reader.ReadString();`

Comment: Why are you using Port 8080? That's usually used by http servers.

Comment: @MindSwipe BinaryReader and BinaryWriter use a format where the string is preceded by a prefix which contains the length of the string. So, there cannot be any fragmentation.

Comment: You are using different encodings for writing (ASCII) and reading (UTF-8) which can cause problems for longer strings. Have you tried using the same encoding at both places?

Comment: Please provide a full [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the effect.

Comment: Try setting the Encoding to ASCII as well when reading, so change `BinaryReader(connectedTcpClient.GetStream()))` to `BinaryReader(connectedTcpClient.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII))`. If this doesn't work you may need to try `Encoding.Unicode` on both ends (as C# uses Unicode (UTF-16) by default)

Comment: @MindSwipe, that was it! I changed the encoding, it works now

Comment: @NineBerry, thanks! i was using different encodings... And did not know about port 8080 will use another, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@NineBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101087/nineberry) pointed out in the comments, you're writing ASCII encoded Bytes, but reading default (Unicode (UTF-16)) Encoded Bytes. Make sure to use the same Encoding on both ends, I'd recommend using Unicode, so either remove `Encoding.ASCII` when instantiating your BinaryWriter or use `Encoding.Unicode` when instantiating your BinaryWriter AND your BinaryReader

Comment: I think you initially meant UTF-8 instead of UTF-16. And, for files and streams, UTF-8 would be the more common choice.